# Ng serve fails on scss error and after fixing it, it doesn't recompile the app

Tags: sass, angular-cli, angular11

I'm using angular 11 with scss. I'm serving the app using  `ng serve --aot` command. It watches the files and compile the app after every change. When there are errors, the CLI detect the it and display the error. After I fix it, it recompiles the files and serves the app.

However, sometimes when there are scss errors, the CLI doesn't detect the changes I make in order to fix the error, and I have to cancel the serve command and rerun it.

For example:
I had an error because I forgot to import a scss file that contained the definition of a variable I used. The CLI showed me the error:
[image: scss error]

I fixed the error and saved the file, but the CLI didn't recompile the files. I had to press `ctrl+c` to cancel the ng-serve command and rerun it, and it worked.

It also happens when I make small changes in SCSS files, like adding "background color" and before I write the color itself, VS code adds ; to the line, creating an error ( because the line is : `background-color: ;`). After fixing it, the CLI doesn't detect the changes.

Any idea why it doesn't detect the changes I make? It happens only in scss errors. when I have TS errors, it detects the fixes perfectly.